# Auto implemented Properties in C# Interfaces

Tags: c#, properties

I am referring to the documentation of Microsoft - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties . They state that auto implemented properties are basically properties without body, when there is no additional logic needed inside a get or set. so `int Myproperty1 {get;set;}` is an auto implemented property. This Documentation also states below points

Statement1:
*"You can't declare auto-implemented properties in interfaces. Auto-implemented properties declare a private instance backing field, and interfaces may not declare instance fields."*

But i can declare auto implemented property like below in an interface

`public MyInterface { int Myproperty1 {get;set;}` . Is this not conflicting above statement that we cant declare auto implemented properties in Interface.

Microsoft documentation then says:
statement2:
*"Declaring a property in an interface without defining a body declares a property with accessors that must be implemented by each type that implements that interface."*

I fail to understand what is declaring a property without body , is it not auto implemented property, if it is then is the first statement not incorrect?

***IMPORTANT EDIT TO THE QUESTION:*** I apologize, I had posted the question with this link by mistake :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/interface-properties.
While I intended to refer to the following link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties. I have updated my question with the correct link now.

Comment: All auto-properties have no bodies, but not all properties without bodies are auto-properties. Neither of the statements is false.

Comment: `Is this not conflicting above statement that we cant declare auto implemented properties in Interface.` No it isn't. It is potentially _confusing_ until you realise that the same `{ get; set; }` syntax means **different things** in interface vs class. In interface it means "the implementing class needs to implement this" (i.e. `"Declaring a property in an interface without defining a body declares a property with accessors that must be implemented by each type that implements that interface."`). While in the class it means "auto implemented property" (with a private instance backing field).

Comment: `But i can declare auto implemented property like below in an interface` No you can't. That _looks_ (to you) like an auto property. But it isn't (by definition - since interfaces can't have auto properties).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSDN never said anything like "all properties without bodies are auto-implemented properties". They might say "auto-implemented properties don't have bodies", but the latter doesn't imply the former. MSDN is not contradicting itself.

Properties without bodies in an interface are `abstract`, whereas auto-implemented properties are those that are non-abstract, without bodies, and in a class/struct.

Therefore, `MyProperty1` in `public MyInterface { int MyProperty1 {get;set;} }` is not an auto-implemented property, but an abstract one.

> I fail to understand what is declaring a property without body

It's just like declaring two methods without bodies in an interface:

```
public MyInterfaceWithTwoMethods {
   int GetMyProperty1();
   void SetMyProperty1(int value);
}
```

Except it's more idiomatic to use properties in C#.

You could *implement* `MyInterface` with an auto-implemented property:

```
public class MyImpl : MyInterface {
    public int MyProperty1 { get; set; }
}
```

Even though you *seem* to be just repeating what is written in `MyInterface`, this is analogous to implementing `MyInterfaceWithTwoMethods` like this:

```
public class MyImpl : MyInterfaceWithTwoMethods {
    private int myProperty1;
    int GetMyProperty1() => myProperty1;
    void SetMyProperty1(int value) { myProperty1 = value; }
}
```

You could also implement `MyInterface` *not* with an auto-implemented property:

```
public class MyImpl : MyInterface {
    public int MyProperty1 { 
        get => 1; 
        set { Console.WriteLine("foo"); } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone who have spent time and effort on this question. Based on responses so far I understand that not every property without body is an auto implemented property. It basically depends in what context is it defined. If it's within a class then its auto implemented but in context of an interface, it's not an auto implemented property.

Comment: Regardless of whether the documentation is correct or not, my opinion is that it's very badly written. Saying "Declaring a property in an interface without defining a body" when that is the only option you have, no body, should be rewritten to show clearer that they're talking about the meaning of the declaration, rather than what happens when you declare it.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I agree that it can be rewritten in a better way. OTOH, perhaps due to my prior knowledge/bias, I find the documentation understandable as it is.